# Outbound Shipment IDOC triggering on change

Tags: sap-erp, idoc

I need to send outbound shipment idoc on change data in VT02N.

```
Message type: SHPMNT.

Basic Type: SHPMNT06.

Extension: SHPMNTEXT.
```

> ```
> Message control:
>
> Application: V7.
>
> Message Type: ZEDI. (output type that i defined for this)
>
> Process Code: SD11.
> ```

I'm able to create idoc perfectly when I create a shipment from VT01N but I'm not able to create it again when i change it.

Kindly help me on this issue.

Thank you.

Talha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to activate the "Multiple Issuing" setting on your message type. The setting should be available through transaction V/82 in the "General data" section of your message type.

Comment: Good point!. Thanks for your answer. But it was not enough for me to only check multiple issuing. I have solved my problem. [Here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3236525) is the link for anyone who needs it.